# JitsiViewController.swift:72:21 : error: value of type 'JitsiMeetConferenceOptionsBuilder' has no member 'welcomePageEnabled'

Tags: swift, flutter, member, jitsi

I am faceing a problem to run flutter app on ios. I am using eko jitsi package for my project. It shows me this type error-

```
Xcode build done.                                           26.0s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/27/0lgprgpd3b52nr55y9txwj7m0000gn/T/flutter_tools.ntxDA9/flutter_i
        os_build_temp_dirSI41Zk/temporary_xcresult_bundle

    /usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/3.3.4/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/eko
    _jitsi-1.3.4/ios/Classes/JitsiViewController.swift:72:21: error: value of type
    'JitsiMeetConferenceOptionsBuilder' has no member 'welcomePageEnabled'
                builder.welcomePageEnabled = true
                ~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    warning: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build
    because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add
    output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build
    by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target
    'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build
    because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add
    output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build
    by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target
    'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    /Users/abir/Documents/Office Work/BuddyBee/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The
    iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but
    the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target
    'OrderedSet' from project 'Pods')

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/27/0lgprgpd3b52nr55y9txwj7m0000gn/T/flutter_tools.ntxDA9/flutter_i
        os_build_temp_dirSI41Zk/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Value of type 'JitsiMeetConferenceOptionsBuilder' has
no member 'welcomePageEnabled'
/usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/3.3.4/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/eko_jit
si-1.3.4/ios/Classes/JitsiViewController.swift:71:20


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
ABIR BuddyBee %
```

**Here is my package `JitsiViewController.swift` file**

```
import UIKit
import JitsiMeetSDK

class JitsiViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var videoButton: UIButton?
    
    fileprivate var pipViewCoordinator: PiPViewCoordinator?
    fileprivate var jitsiMeetView: JitsiMeetView?
    
    var eventSink:FlutterEventSink? = nil
    var roomName:String? = nil
    var serverUrl:URL? = nil
    var subject:String? = nil
    var audioOnly:Bool? = false
    var audioMuted: Bool? = false
    var videoMuted: Bool? = false
    var token:String? = nil
    var featureFlags: Dictionary<String, Bool>? = Dictionary();
    
    
    var jistiMeetUserInfo = JitsiMeetUserInfo()
    
    override func loadView() {
        
        super.loadView()
    }
    
    @objc func openButtonClicked(sender : UIButton){
        
        //openJitsiMeetWithOptions();
    }
    
    @objc func closeButtonClicked(sender : UIButton){
        cleanUp();
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        //print("VIEW DID LOAD")
        self.view.backgroundColor = .black
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        openJitsiMeet();
    }
    
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize,
                                     with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size)
        pipViewCoordinator?.resetBounds(bounds: rect)
    }

    // This is needed to avoid the Flutter view behind it, to be hit by touch events.
    // See: 
    // https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14720
    // https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35784#issuecomment-516243057
    open override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {}
    
    func openJitsiMeet() {
        cleanUp()
        // create and configure jitsimeet view
        let jitsiMeetView = JitsiMeetView()
        
        
        jitsiMeetView.delegate = self
        self.jitsiMeetView = jitsiMeetView
        let options = JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.fromBuilder { (builder) in
            builder.welcomePageEnabled = true
            builder.room = self.roomName
            builder.serverURL = self.serverUrl            
            builder.userInfo = self.jistiMeetUserInfo
            builder.token = self.token
            
            self.featureFlags?.forEach{ key,value in
                builder.setFeatureFlag(key, withValue: value);
            }
            builder.setAudioOnly(self.audioOnly!);
            builder.setAudioMuted(self.audioMuted!);
            builder.setVideoMuted(self.videoMuted!);
            builder.setSubject(self.subject!);
            
        }
        
        jitsiMeetView.join(options)
        
        // Enable jitsimeet view to be a view that can be displayed
        // on top of all the things, and let the coordinator to manage
        // the view state and interactions
        pipViewCoordinator = PiPViewCoordinator(withView: jitsiMeetView)
        pipViewCoordinator?.configureAsStickyView(withParentView: view)
        
        // animate in
        jitsiMeetView.alpha = 0
        pipViewCoordinator?.show()
    }
    
    func closeJitsiMeeting(){
        jitsiMeetView?.leave()
    }
    
    fileprivate func cleanUp() {
        jitsiMeetView?.removeFromSuperview()
        jitsiMeetView = nil
        pipViewCoordinator = nil
        //self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension JitsiViewController: JitsiMeetViewDelegate {
    
    func conferenceWillJoin(_ data: [AnyHashable : Any]!) {
        //        print("CONFERENCE WILL JOIN")
        var mutatedData = data
        mutatedData?.updateValue("onConferenceWillJoin", forKey: "event")
        self.eventSink?(mutatedData)
    }
    
    func conferenceJoined(_ data: [AnyHashable : Any]!) {
        //        print("CONFERENCE JOINED")
        var mutatedData = data
        mutatedData?.updateValue("onConferenceJoined", forKey: "event")
        self.eventSink?(mutatedData)
    }
    
    func conferenceTerminated(_ data: [AnyHashable : Any]!) {
        //        print("CONFERENCE TERMINATED")
        var mutatedData = data
        mutatedData?.updateValue("onConferenceTerminated", forKey: "event")
        self.eventSink?(mutatedData)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.pipViewCoordinator?.hide() { _ in
                self.cleanUp()
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    func enterPicture(inPicture data: [AnyHashable : Any]!) {
        //        print("CONFERENCE PIP")\
        var mutatedData = data
        mutatedData?.updateValue("onPictureInPictureWillEnter", forKey: "event")
        self.eventSink?(mutatedData)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.pipViewCoordinator?.enterPictureInPicture()
        }
    }

    func exitPictureInPicture() {
        //        print("CONFERENCE PIP OUT")
        var mutatedData : [AnyHashable : Any]
        mutatedData = ["event":"onPictureInPictureTerminated"]
        self.eventSink?(mutatedData)
    }

    func onWhiteboardClicked() {
        //        print("CONFERENCE PIP OUT")
        var mutatedData : [AnyHashable : Any]
        mutatedData = ["event":"onWhiteboardClicked"]
        self.eventSink?(mutatedData)
    }
}


extension UIColor {
    public convenience init?(hex: String) {
        let r, g, b, a: CGFloat

        if hex.hasPrefix("#") {
            let start = hex.index(hex.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
            let hexColor = String(hex[start...])

            if hexColor.count == 8 {
                let scanner = Scanner(string: hexColor)
                var hexNumber: UInt64 = 0

                if scanner.scanHexInt64(&hexNumber) {
                    r = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0xff000000) >> 24) / 255
                    g = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x00ff0000) >> 16) / 255
                    b = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x0000ff00) >> 8) / 255
                    a = CGFloat(hexNumber & 0x000000ff) / 255

                    self.init(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
                    return
                }
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Where is the problem in this swift code ? How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the object `JitsiMeetConferenceOptions` in your `openJitsiMeet` method has not the attribute `welcomePageEnabled`.

The simplest way to fix is remove `builder.welcomePageEnabled = true` and look if there are any errors.
You've probably updated the library and there are some old references to the functions.

Probably `welcomePageEnabled` has been renamed or removed from sdk.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `2.11.0` version in order to set the `welcomePageEnabled` property . But this version is too old, I suggest to migrate to a newer one.